# the reply cannot be received until the current Message completes processing

Tags: wcf, dns, local

I was create a wcf project service by 2 program

first ( wcf Service) web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel> 

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name ="svcbh">

                    <serviceDiscovery>
                    <announcementEndpoints>
                        <endpoint kind="udpAnnouncementEndpoint"></endpoint>
                    </announcementEndpoints>
                    </serviceDiscovery>

                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>

                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->

        <services>
            <service name ="WCF.Service.Service1" behaviorConfiguration ="svcbh" >
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/Service1/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint name ="duplexendpoint"
                          address =""
                          binding ="wsDualHttpBinding"
                          contract ="WCF.Service.IService1"/>
                <endpoint name ="MetaDataTcpEndpoint"
                          address="mex"
                          binding="mexHttpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>

    </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and in my client project ( app.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SecureBinding">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="duplexendpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    transactionFlow="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
                <binding name="duplexendpoint1" />
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://92.168.1.199:9000/Service1/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="duplexendpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="duplexendpoint">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="khorramak@adrco.local" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/Service1/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="duplexendpoint1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="duplexendpoint1">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="MyName" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>

    </system.serviceModel>
<appSettings>

<add key="connectionstring"  value="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=a;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Serita;Data Source=.;"  />

</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

i run it n local Run successfully
but i have run into Domain , I hate the metod proxy.open();
code for open proxy

```
public partial class HQMSSyncForm : Form, IService1Callback
    {
        Service1Client proxy;
        public HQMSSyncForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
                proxy = new Service1Client(context);
                proxy.Open(); // Error this Line
                proxy.RegisterClient();
                ClinicService.Instance.SetConnectionString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionstring"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in HQMS is : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve my problem
when you see this error

```
The caller was not authenticated by the service.
```

check Windows authentication is installed or no in Windows Server (for install Feuture -> add Feuture -> Dot net xxx -> WCF Service)

first intall it
after in client side
if user in domain server have a password comment this line in app.config

```
<identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="MyName" />
                </identity>
```

so , befor open proxy add this lines

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
       proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "Username";
       proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "DomainName";
```

success :-)